# Importing CSV file to MySQL including structure

Tags: mysql, csv, import, structure

I understand that there are several ways of importing a csv file to an existing mysql table (load date, phpmyadmin, etc.). But what if the target mysql table doesn't exist yet? How can you automatically create one with the structure of a given csv file?

Answer (score 2):

CSV using `LOAD DATA` is not what you're after. I haven't found any way to do this with MySQL or phpMyAdmin. [This tool](http://convertcsvtomysql.com/) wasn't what I was after as it sets every data type to `VARCHAR (255)` regardless of the fields' contents but for an uncommon problem, it just might do the trick (after some manual edits).

Answer (score 0):

There definitely is a way, with a little scripting but a quick way to do it is phpMyAdmin.
Go to the database page, create one if you don't have one already (note:not the table page)
After selecting your database, you should see the tables listed if you have any.
click on import on the top, then choose CSV instead of SQL as the file type 
then check mark,
The first line of the file contains the table column names (if this is unchecked, the first line will become part of the data)
That's it, submit the form!